# There is type "time" in SQL language?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was writing some code in SQL , and i wanted to write the type for hours . I did search and i found type **TIMESTAMP** and **DATETIME** , i just want a type to represent only the **time** not the date.

Thanks in advice , sorry for my english

Comment: this is highly dependent on the database engine (and version) that you are using. Is it Oracle?, MySQL?, SQL Server?, Postgresql?.....

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  The normal data type for hours is `int`.  But if you want more refined times, then many databases support a `time` datatype.

Comment: I fail to understand how a simple Google search did not give you your answer.

Comment: A simple google search for "sql server datatypes" would reveal this link as the top result. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx It is the official documentation for sql server. You should become familiar with it as it contains all the information required for your question here.

Comment: Just be aware that in SQL Server `timestamp` is something totally different what you might expect. The alias `rowversion` describes it a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

> i just want a type to represent only the time not the date..

```
 --for sql server versions 2005 and 2008
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),108)

--declaring part
declare @a varchar(10)
set @a=convert(varchar(10),getdate(),108)
 select @a

--from sql server 2012
select cast(getdate() as time)

select format(getdate(),'hh:mm:ss')

-declaring part---
 declare @a time=getdate()
select @a
```

Comment: added some examples,let me know if this is what you are looking for